# I'm having trouble with the syntax for my compare function for javascript

Tags: javascript, function, compare, syntax-error

I've included a screenshot image of a codeacademy error I made today. I'm trying to create a compare function that randomly picks a number between 0 and 1 (paper, scissors, or rock) that inputs two choices and returns the winner based on how choice1 compares to choice2.

The first part is a comment, but it explains how the original paper scissors rock function was built

Here is the code:

```
/*var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}*/

var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {if (choice1 === choice2) return("The result is a tie!");  
if (choice1 < 0.34) 
if(choice2 ==="scissors");
    return("rock wins");
} else if(choice2 ==="paper");{
    return("paper wins");
};    
};
```

It's telling me that there's an unexpected token else on line 15 (the else if line)

When I erase the else part it gives me another syntax error saying the same thing about a token if. I'm stuck on what part of my syntax is off and how to fix it.

Comment: compare with the commented code to find the extra `semicolons` used.

Comment: just as a sidenote: if choice1 is a randomly picked number and choice2 is either "scissors", "rock" or "paper", your if statement `if (choice1 === choice2)` will never be `true`. You should choose one format (either number between 0 and 1 or one of the three strings) and pass both, choice1 and choice2 to your compare function in the same format.

Comment: This is a good point. I'll be careful about that in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it has something to do with `===` and the `;` after the `if()` statements, either way, here is a nicer way of comparing them.

```
function compare(a,b)
{
    if(a==b)return "draw";
    switch(a)
    {
        case "rock":return (b=="scissors"?a:b)+" wins";
        case "paper":return (b=="rock"?a:b)+" wins";
        case "scissors":return (b=="paper"?a:b)+" wins";
    }
}
console.log(compare("scissors","paper"));
```

Comment: This would probably work, but since I haven't been instructed on how to use cases at this point in the lesson I was hesitant to try it. I'm still going to use this syntax as a reference for when I'm asked to use cases though. Thanks for the help Isaac.

Comment: No problem, `switch` and `case` are one of the few `goto` type statements that no one frowns on you for using.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments on semicolon related errors below.

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) return("The result is a tie!");  

  if (choice1 < 0.34) {

    if(choice2 === "scissors") { // remove ; here
      return("rock wins");
    } else if (choice2 === "paper") { // remove ; here
      return("paper wins");
    } // remove ; here

  } // add another else => what happens when choice1 >= 0.34 (not a rock)
};
```

With the required `else` blocks the complete function would look like:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) return("The result is a tie!");  

  if (choice1 < 0.34) { // rock

    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
      return("rock wins");
    } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
      return("paper wins");
    }

  } else if (choice <= 0.67) { // paper

    if(choice2 === "rock") {
      return("paper wins");
    } else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return("scissors wins");
    }

  } else { // scissors

    if(choice2 === "paper") {
      return("scissors wins");
    } else if (choice2 === "rock") {
      return("rock wins");
    }

  }
};
```

***EDIT***
This is just to help you overcome the confusion over semicolons if any. Usually a function definition is not required to have a `;` after its body completes by putting the last closing curly brace `}`.

```
function compare (choice1, choice2) {
  // ...
}
```

On the contrary, when we assign a variable a value, the statement is terminated by a semicolon.

```
var name = "John Doe";
```

Hence, when we combine the two, we're defining a function and then using it in an assignment statement which needs to be closed by using a semicolon. Hence, the syntax:

```
var compare = function (choice2, choice2) {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: This code worked properly. I'm going to study it more but I like how you structured it and separated each condition to help me visually follow. I particularly found the inclusion of comments in the if/else statements helpful in organizing the code. Maybe it was the way you specified every possible outcome that (including the difference scenarios for choice 1). I don't know if I mentioned that it was supposed to be a given that choice 1 was rock. (That was mentioned in the intstructions). Thanks so much for your help. I'm going to refer back to this format in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }

  if (choice1 < 0.34) {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return "rock wins";
    } else if (choice2 === "paper") {
      return "paper wins";
    }
  }
}
```